# jQuery not parsing nested XML correctly

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing

I'm parsing data from my xml which looks like this:

```
<departuresData> 
<station> 
  <id>29411</id> 
  <name>Kúpalisko Matador</name> 
  <distance>182</distance> 
  <vehicle> 
    <number>180</number> 
    <time>10:26</time> 
    <time>10:56</time> 
    <target>Holíčska</target> 
    <lineid>289</lineid> 
    <type>BUS</type> 
  </vehicle> 
  <vehicle> 
    <number>180</number> 
    <time>10:17</time> 
    <time>10:47</time> 
    <target>Cintorín Petržalka</target> 
    <lineid>288</lineid> 
    <type>BUS</type> 
  </vehicle> 
</station> 
<station> 
  <id>30122</id> 
  <name>Kúpalisko Matador</name> 
  <distance>201</distance> 
  <vehicle> 
    <number>80</number> 
    <time>10:09</time> 
    <time>10:33</time> 
    <target>Kollárovo nám.</target> 
    <lineid>220</lineid> 
    <type>BUS</type> 
  </vehicle> 
  <vehicle> 
    <number>80</number> 
    <time>10:02</time> 
    <time>10:26</time> 
    <target>Kúpalisko Matador</target> 
    <lineid>222</lineid> 
    <type>BUS</type> 
  </vehicle> 
</station> 
<departuresData>
```

and my parsing jquery looks like:

```
success: function(xml) {
 $(xml).find("station").each(function()
  {

    //vydolovanie hodnot
    var name = $(this).find("name").text();
    var distance = $(this).find("distance").text();
    $("#response").append("Zastavka:" + name + "<br />Vzdialenost:" + distance + "<br />");  //vypis

    $(this).find("vehicle").each(function(){

        var number = $(this).find("number").text();
        var target = $(this).find("target").text();
        var type = $(this).find("type").text();

            $("#response").append("Linka cislo: " + number + "<br />Smer: " + target + "<br />Druh: " + type + "<br />Časy:<br />");
        $(this).find("time").each(function()
        {
            $("#response").append($(this).text() + "<br />"); //vypis
        });

        $("#response").append("1<br /><br />"); //vypis

    });

    $("#response").append("<br />");
  });
```

}

but it only comes to distance, and when it has to look into each vehicle part for some reason it can't get info which is in number, time and so on. And also it not loops through all vehicle tags in  one station tag.

Output looks like:

```
Zastavka:Kúpalisko Matador
Vzdialenost:198
Linka cislo: 
Smer: 
Druh: 
Časy:

1


Zastavka:Kúpalisko Matador
Vzdialenost:201
Linka cislo: 
Smer: 
Druh: 
Časy:

1
```

Comment: Are you using firebug in mozilla or chrome's inbuilt web developer tools?
I know i'm not answering your question directly but you're gonna have SOOO much more of these syntax/logic errors that you should just step through your code.

In chrome, you can right click and 'inspect element'. Under the scripts tab, you can look through all js enabled on the page and set breakpoints on your code.

Comment: thank you for answer Joe, i look into chrome js scope variables and it looks like there's nothing in number tag and the same in the others.

Comment: did it find the vehicle? i.e put a breakpoint inside your var number = $(this).find("number").text(); is it actually hitting the bp?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on looking closer, your first output:

```
Vzdialenost:198
```

states that the distance is 198. However, your xml does not have a distance of 198. 
There's

```
<distance>182</distance>
```

and

```
<distance>201</distance>
```

so either you've pasted the wrong question or you're not actually reading from the right xml.